# Program that adjust computer lighting based on time of day?

Tags: wallpaper

What is the program that adjusts the lighting of your computer based on the time of day / lighting? For example, turning bright afternoon it would increase the brightness, during night it would dim & lighten the screen.

Comment: You not even mention which OS and version you are using, so how would one go about recommending something? In Windows 8.1 and up some PCs have an option to adjust brightness automatically (the PC must have an ambient light sensor, so it is not available on all PCs.)

Comment: Sorry about that, I'm using Windows 10 on a Dell XPS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [flux](https://justgetflux.com/). But it does things a little differently from what you described. It adjusts redness as well as brightness. During the day, your screen will be bright and normal colored. At sunset (it asks for your location to get the timing correct) it dims down and strips out a lot of the blue light and becomes more red. The blue light is what makes the screen so bright. At sunrise, it becomes bright again.